# jQuery form validator

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, validation, plugin

I am new to the world of jQuery plugins, I don't know why I didn't get into this sooner. What I have a working validator that validates bootstrap styled forms. What I have discovered is that the way it is set up causes error when there are more than one form on the page. I would like to know how to make it more efficient so that a few things can be accomplished:

- I would like to be able to use it on multiple forms on a page
- I would like to see if it can be consolidated further than I already have it
- Is the code optimal

```
!function($){

    var Validator = function(form, mode, options){
        this.$form = form;
        this.mode = mode;
        this.options = options;
        this.valid = true;
        this.ccImagePath = null;
        this.controlsArray = [];
    };

    Validator.prototype = { 
        constructor : Validator,
        init : function(){
            var that = this,
            mode = this.mode,
            form = this.$form;
            switch(mode){
                case "set" :
                    that.setControls();
                    for(var x in that.controlsArray){

                        that.onKeyInput(that.controlsArray[x]);
                    }
                    break;
                case "check" :
                    that.getControlsArray();
                    if(!that.finalValidation()){
                        that.valid = false;
                    }else{
                        that.valid = true;
                    }
                    break;  
                case "cc" :
                    that.ccImagePath = that.options.path;
                    that.generateCreditCardHolder(that.options.target);
                    that.setCreditCardImage();
                    break;
                default :
                    console.log("Invalid mode set, use 'set' or 'check'");
            }
        },
        'setControls' : function(){
            var options = this.options;
            var form = this.$form;
            var that = this;
            for(var key in options){
                switch(key){
                    case 'notEmpty' :
                    case 'isString' :
                    case 'isEmail' :
                    case 'isPhoneNumber':
                    case 'isNumber':
                    case 'isURL' :
                    case 'isSSN' :
                    case 'isRoutingNumber' :
                    case 'isMacAddress' :
                    case 'isIPAddress' :
                    case 'isCreditCard' :
                    case 'isZipCode' :
                    case 'isCreditCard':
                    case 'validPassword':
                        for(var selector in options[key]){
                            this.setData(options[key][selector], ''+key+'');
                            this.setDataTarget(options[key][selector]);
                            this.setControlsArray(options[key][selector]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'isDateTime' :
                        for(var selector in options[key]){
                            if(Array.isArray(options[key])){
                                var defaultDateFormat = 'm/d/Y';
                                var selectors = options[key];
                                for(var i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++){
                                    if(typeof selectors[i] === 'string'){
                                        this.setData(selectors[i], ''+key+''+defaultDateFormat);
                                        this.setDataTarget(selectors[i]);
                                        that.setControlsArray(selectors[i]);        
                                    }else if(Array.isArray(selectors[i])){
                                        if(selectors[i].length < 2 || selectors[i].length > 2){
                                            console.log("isDateTime Error: when passing an array within an array the first argument is the selector as a string, and the second arguments is the pattern as a string");
                                        }else{
                                            var tag = selectors[i][0];
                                            var format = selectors[i][1];
                                            that.setData(tag, ''+key+''+format);
                                            that.setDataTarget(tag);
                                            that.setControlsArray(tag);
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        console.log("isDateTime Error: incorrect type of input for validation. Please see documentation.");
                                    }
                                }
                            }else if(typeof options[key] === 'object'){
                                this.setData(selector, ''+key+''+options[key][selector]+'');
                                this.setDataTarget(selector);
                                that.setControlsArray(selector);
                            }else{
                                console.log("isDateTime Error: incorrect input options. Please pass either an object in a '#selector' : 'pattern' format, or a mixed array of selectors as strings or array of selector with patterns");
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'isDependent' : 
                    case 'equalTo' :
                    case 'testRegex' : 
                        for(var selector in options[key]){
                            this.setData(selector, ''+key+''+options[key][selector]+'');
                            this.setDataTarget(selector);
                            that.setControlsArray(selector);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'groupNotEmpty' : 
                        for(var selector in options[key]){

                            $(form).find(options[key][selector]+':first').data('validator', ''+key);
                            $(form).find(options[key][selector]+':first').data('validator-target', options[key][selector]);
                            that.setControlsArray(options[key][selector]);
                        }
                }
            }
        },
        'getControlsArray' : function(){
            var that = this;
            var form = that.$form;
            $(form).find('input, select, textarea').each(function(){
                var data = $(this).data('validator-target');
                if(data){
                    if($.inArray(data, that.controlsArray) === -1){
                        that.controlsArray.push(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        'setControlsArray' : function(selector){
            var that = this;
            if($.inArray(selector, that.controlsArray) === -1){
                that.controlsArray.push(selector);
            }
        },
        'setData' : function(selector, key){
            var form = this.$form;
            var data = $(form).find(selector).data('validator');
            if(!data){
                $(form).find(selector).data('validator', key);
            }else{
                data += '|'+key;
                $(form).find(selector).data('validator', data);
            }
        },
        'setDataTarget' : function(selector){
            var form = this.$form;
            var data = $(form).find(selector).data('validator-target');
            var type = $(form).find(selector).attr('type');
            if(!data){
                if(type != 'radio' && type != 'checkbox'){
                    $(form).find(selector).data('validator-target', selector);
                }else{
                    data = $(form).find(selector+':first').data('validator-target', selector);
                    if(!data){
                        $(form).find(selector+':first').data('validator-target', selector);
                    }
                    data = $(form).find(selector+':first').data('validator-target');
                }
            }
        },
        'generateCreditCardHolder' : function(selector){
            var form = this.$form,
            that = this;
            $(form).find(selector).closest('.form-group').each(function(){
                $(this).closest('.form-group').append("<div id='cardImageHolder'></div>");
            });
        },
        'setCreditCardImage' : function(cardname){
            var form = this.$form;
            that = this;
            var cardname = cardname;
            if(!cardname){
                cardname = 'cc';
            }
            file = that.ccImagePath+"img/"+cardname+".jpg";
            // search out the credit 
            $('#cardImageHolder').html('<img src="'+file+'" width="100%" />' );
        },
        'onKeyInput' : function(selector){
            var form = this.$form;
            var that = this;
            var data = $(form).find(selector).data('validator');
            var type = $(form).find(selector).attr('type');
            $(form).find(selector).bind('change keyup click select focus', function(){
                if(data){
                    that.validator(selector);
                }
                console.log(selector);
            });     
        },
        'finalValidation' : function(){
            var that = this;
            var rVal = true;
            var arr = that.controlsArray;

            for(var x in arr){

                if(!that.validator(that.controlsArray[x])){

                    rVal = false;
                }
            }
            return rVal;
        },
        // work on making validator a shorter function and even further change how the function is used with the plugin
        'validator' : function(selector){
            var form = this.$form;
            var that = this;
            var rVal = true;
            var element = selector;
            // find all the input elements in the form to begin the validation process
            $(form).find(element).each(function(){

                var errors = 0;
                //check if there is a validator option for the specific input and that it has a value to it
                if($(this).data('validator')){

                    // get the element type and split the pipe separated values into an array
                    var value = null;
                    var type = $(this).attr('type');
                    if(type != "radio" && type != "checkbox"){
                        value = $(this).val();
                    }else{
                        var name = $(this).attr('name');
                        value = [];
                        $(element+":checked").each(function(){
                            value.push($(this).val());
                        });
                    }

                    // check the .data('validator') string to accoutn for interior pipes that may be used with regexes or selectors
                    var validations = $(this).data('validator');
                    validations = validations.replace(/\|\=/g, '%=');
                    var holding = [];
                    if(validations.indexOf('testRegex') > -1){
                        var hold = validations.substring(validations.indexOf('testRegex'), validations.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                        holding.push(hold);
                        validations = validations.replace(hold, '');
                    }
                    validations = validations.replace("||", "|");
                    validations = validations.split('|');
                    validations = validations.concat(holding);
                    for(var x in validations){
                        validations[x] = validations[x].replace('%=', '|=');
                    }
                    validations = validations.filter(function(n){return n != undefined && n != ""});
                    for(var i = 0; i < validations.length; i++){
                        if(validations[i].indexOf('isDateTime') !== -1){
                            var regex = validations[i].replace('isDateTime', '');
                            !that.isDateTime(value, regex) ? errors++ : null;
                        }else if(validations[i].indexOf('equalTo') !== -1){
                            var selector = validations[i].replace('equalTo', '');
                            !that.equalTo(value, selector) ? errors++ : null;
                        }else if(validations[i].indexOf('isDependent') !== -1){
                            var selector = validations[i].replace('isDependent', '');
                            !that.isDependent(value, selector) ? errors++ : null;
                        }else if(validations[i].indexOf('testRegex') !== -1){
                            var regex = validations[i].replace('testRegex', '');
                            var regex = regex.substring(regex.indexOf('/')+1, regex.lastIndexOf('/'));
                            !that.testRegex(value, regex) ? errors++ : null;
                        }else{
                            !that[validations[i]](value) ? errors++ : null;
                        }
                    }
                    if(errors > 0){
                        if(type != "radio" && type != "checkbox"){
                            $(this).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                        }else{
                            $(this).closest('.radio, .checkbox, .radio-inline, .checkbox-inline').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(type != "radio" && type != "checkbox"){
                            $(this).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                        }else{
                            $(this).closest('.radio, .checkbox, .radio-inline, .checkbox-inline').closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(errors > 0) rVal = false;
            });
            return rVal;
        },
        notEmpty : function(value){
            return value && $.trim(value).length > 0;
        },
        required : function(value){
            return value && $.trim(value).length > 0;
        },
        isEmail : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length)
                check = /^([^@\s\t\n]+\@[\w\d]+\.[\w]{2,3}(\.[\w]{2})?)$/.test(value);
            return check;
        },
        isPhoneNumber : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length)
                check = /^(\d\-)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\-|\s]?\d{3}[\-|\s]?\d{4}$/.test(value);
            return check;
        }, 
        isNumber : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length)
                check = /^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(value);
            return check;
        },
        isSSN : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length)
                check = /^\d{3}\-?\d{2}\-?\d{4}$/.test(value);
            return check;
        },
        isString : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length)
                check = /^\D+$/.test(value);
            return check;
        },
        isURL : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length)
                check = /^([http\:\/\/]+)?([a-zA-Z]+)?\.?[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(value);
            return check;
        },
        isDateTime : function(value, regex){
            var check = true;
            if(regex == null){
                return true;
            }
            var regexChars = regex.split("");
            var pattern = "^";
            for(var i = 0; i < regexChars.length; i++){
                switch(regexChars[i]){
                    case "d" : 
                    case "j" :
                        pattern = pattern + "(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])";
                        break;
                    case "D":
                        pattern = pattern + "(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)";
                    case "l" :
                        pattern = pattern + "(Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday)";
                        break;
                    case "F" :
                        pattern = pattern + "(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)";
                        break;
                    case "M" :
                        pattern = pattern + "(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)";
                        break;
                    case "m" :
                    case "n" :
                        pattern = pattern + "(0?[1-9]|1[012])";
                        break;
                    case "Y" :
                    case "y" :
                        pattern = pattern + "(19|20)?[\\d]+";
                        break;
                    case "a" :
                    case "A" :
                        pattern = pattern + "([AaPp][Mm])";
                        break;
                    case "g" :
                    case "G" :
                    case "h" :
                    case "H" :
                        pattern = pattern + "(0?[1-9]|1[012]|2[0123])";
                        break;
                    case "i" :
                    case "s" :
                        pattern = pattern + "([012345][0-9])";
                        break;
                    case "/" :
                        pattern = pattern + "[/]";
                        break;
                    case ":" :
                        pattern = pattern + "[:]";
                        break;
                    case "." : 
                        pattern = pattern + "[.]";
                        break;
                    case " " :
                        pattern = pattern + "[ ]";
                        break;
                    case "," :
                        pattern = pattern + "[,]";
                        break;
                    case "-" :
                        pattern = pattern + "[-]";
                        break;
                }
            }
            pattern = pattern+"$";

            pattern = new RegExp(pattern, 'i');

            if(value.length)
                check = pattern.test(value);
            return check;
        },
        groupNotEmpty : function(value){
            return value.length > 0;
        },
        isRoutingNumber : function(value){
            //run through each digit and calculate the total
            var n = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i += 3){
                n += parseInt(value.charAt(i), 10)*3 + parseInt(value.charAt(i+1), 10)*7 + parseInt(value.charAt(i+2), 10);
            }
            //if the resulting sum is an even multiple of ten (but not zero), the aba routing number is good
            if(n != 0 && n % 10 == 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        },
        isMacAddress : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length){
                check = /^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$/.test(value);
            }
            return check;
        },
         isIPAddress : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length){
                check = /^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/.test(value);
            }
            return check;
        },
        validPassword : function(value){
            var check = false;
            var strength = 0;

            if(value.length > 7){
                 strength += 4;   
            }
            // password mixins
            var variations = {
                digits: /[0-9]/.test(value),
                lower: /[a-z]/.test(value),
                upper: /[A-Z]/.test(value),
                nonWords: /[!$@#]/.test(value)
            };
            for (var item in variations) {
                strength += (variations[item] == true) ? 1 : 0;
            }
            if(strength >= 6){
                check = true;
            }
            return check;
        },
        equalTo : function(value, selector){
            var form = this.$form;
            var check = false;
            var checkValue = $(form).find(selector).val();
            if(value.length){
                if(value === checkValue){
                    check = true;
                }
            }
            return check;
        },
        isCreditCard : function(value){
            var that = this;
            var check = false;
            var value = value.replace(/[ -]/g, '');
            var card_types = [
                {
                    name : 'amex',
                    pattern: /^3[47]/,
                    valid_length: [15]
                }, {
                    //diners_club_carte_blanche
                    name: 'dccb',
                    pattern: /^30[0-5]/,
                    valid_length: [14]
                }, {
                    //diners_club_international
                    name: 'dci',
                    pattern: /^36/,
                    valid_length: [14]
                }, {
                    name: 'jcb',
                    pattern: /^35(2[89]|[3-8][0-9])/,
                    valid_length: [16]
                }, {
                    name: 'laser',
                    pattern: /^(6304|670[69]|6771)/,
                    valid_length: [16, 17, 18, 19]
                }, {
                    //visa_electron
                    name: 'electron',
                    pattern: /^(4026|417500|4508|4844|491(3|7))/,
                    valid_length: [16]
                }, {
                    name: 'visa',
                    pattern: /^4/,
                    valid_length: [16]
                }, {
                    //mastercard
                    name: 'mc',
                    pattern: /^5[1-5]/,
                    valid_length: [16]
                }, {
                    name: 'maestro',
                    pattern: /^(5018|5020|5038|6304|6759|676[1-3])/,
                    valid_length: [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
                }, {
                    name: 'discover',
                    pattern: /^(6011|622(12[6-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|[2-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-1][0-9]|92[0-5]|64[4-9])|65)/,
                    valid_length: [16]
                }
            ];

            if(value.length){
                var exists = false;
                var matches = false;
                var validlength = false;
                var validLuhn = false;
                var cardname = "";
                that.setCreditCardImage(cardname);
                for(var name in card_types){
                    if(value.match(card_types[name].pattern)){
                        matches = true;
                    }
                    if(card_types[name].valid_length.indexOf(value.length) > -1){
                        validlength = true;
                    }
                    if(matches && validlength){
                        cardname = card_types[name].name.toLowerCase();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(matches && validlength){
                    var digit, n, sum, j, len, ref1;
                    sum = 0;
                    ref1 = value.split('').reverse();
                    for(n = j = 0, len = ref1.length; j < len; n = ++j){
                        digit = ref1[n];
                        digit = +digit;
                        if(n % 2){
                            digit *= 2;
                            if(digit < 10){
                                sum += digit;
                            }else{
                                sum += digit - 9;
                            }
                        }else{
                            sum += digit;
                        }
                    }
                    if(sum % 10 === 0){
                        validLuhn = true;
                    }           
                }else{
                    return check;
                }
                if(matches && validlength && validLuhn){
                    check = true;
                    that.setCreditCardImage(cardname);
                    return check;
                }else{
                    that.setCreditCardImage();
                    return check;
                }
            }else{
                check = true;
                return check;
                that.setCreditCardImage();
            }

        },
        isZipCode : function(value){
            var check = true;
            if(value.length){
                check = /^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/.test(value);
            }
            return check; 
        },
        isDependent : function(value, selector){
            var check = true;
            if(selector.length){
                if(selector.substring(0,1) === '_'){
                    selector = "[data-validator*=isDependent"+selector+"]";
                }
                if(!this.notEmpty(value)){
                    form.find(selector).each(function(){
                        if($(this).val() !== ''){
                            check = false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            return check;
        },
        testRegex : function(value, regex){
            var check = true;
            var caret = regex.substring(0);
            var dollar = regex.substring(regex.length-1);
            if(caret != "^")
                regex = "^"+regex;
            if(dollar != "$")
                regex = regex+'$';
            if(value.length && regex.length){
                var pattern = new RegExp(regex, 'i');
                check = pattern.test(value);
            }
            return check;
        }
    };
    $.fn.validator = function(){
        var _data = null;
        var _mode = null;
        if(arguments.length){
            _mode = "set";
            _data = arguments[0];
        }else{
            console.log("dataval failed! Please supply an options object for the fields to properly be set");
        }
        var _Validator = new Validator(this, _mode, _data);
        _Validator.init();
        return this;
    };
    $.fn.validator.setCCImage = function(selector){
        var _data = selector;
        var _mode = "cc";
        var _Validator = new Validator(this, _mode, _data);
        _Validator.init();
        return this;
    };
    $.fn.validator.check = function(){
        console.log(this);

        var _data = null;
        var _mode = "check";
        var _Validator = new Validator(this, _mode, _data);
        _Validator.init();
        return _Validator.valid;
    };
    $.fn.validator.Constructor = Validator;

}( window.jQuery );
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! If you have some HTML for it you can [edit] the post and use Ctrl+M to embed an executable snippet for reviewers to test and play with.

Comment: You shouldn't need a `var that` if your addressing this in the function only if your passing it to a child scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly looking through your code...

```
                if(!that.finalValidation()){
                    that.valid = false;
                }else{
                    that.valid = true;
                }
```

This sort of stuff can be assigned directly:

```
that.valid = that.finalValidation();
```

---

```
        var cardname = cardname;
        if(!cardname){
            cardname = 'cc';
        }
```

Shorthand for this sort of stuff is `var cardname = cardname || 'cc';`...

```
   'setCreditCardImage' : function(cardname){
        var form = this.$form;
        that = this;
        var cardname = cardname;
        if(!cardname){
            cardname = 'cc';
        }
        file = that.ccImagePath+"img/"+cardname+".jpg";
        // search out the credit 
        $('#cardImageHolder').html('<img src="'+file+'" width="100%" />' );
    },
```

But you shouldn't be declaring a variable with the same name as an argument anyway, because it does magical things in javascript (primarily, redefining variables sets them to undefined, even if the code is never executed).

So just use like this:

```
   'setCreditCardImage' : function(cardname){
        var form = this.$form;
        that = this;
        cardname = cardname || 'cc';
        file = that.ccImagePath+"img/"+cardname+".jpg";
        // search out the credit 
        $('#cardImageHolder').html('<img src="'+file+'" width="100%" />' );
    },
```